# Get a Google Cloud Messaging Device ID and Token without building a client

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Due to some specific circumstances, I found myself needing to setup an GCM app server that will accept device tokens and push some data to Google Servers, and I need some test tokens to play around with my app server without bothering my teammates who will be building the clients (in a few weeks). However I have no experience building iOS, Android, or Chrome apps, which are to my knowledge the only three ways actually generate such a token. Any idea why GCM does not offer a way to simulate a device?

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase Cloud Messaging Instance ID token identifies the installation of a specific app on a specific device. Without having both an app and a device, there cannot be a device token.

An easy way to think of it: what are you sending a message to? If there is no app, then how will the device know how to display the message and what to do if the user clicks it? And how would a user be able to stop from receiving notifications, if there isn't a specific app (and thus token) that is being targeted?

Comment: I understand that, but since they only allow chrome extensions, android, and iPhone apps, I thought they might provide a test environment where you, as a server app writer, can interact with "mock" devices, because obviously not everyone will be able to spin apps in those devices just to get a fake token. I ended up creating a chrome extension to get the token, but I am just surprised this is not possible to do otherwise.